# Why didn't Jason Ironheart protect Talia's personality?

Tags: babylon-5

In the Babylon 5 episode [Mind War](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Mind_War) Jason Ironheart departs his physical existence and in parting grants Talia Winters, his former lover, the gift of telekinesis as well as enhanced telepathic abilities (as seen in [A Race Through Dark Places](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/A_Race_Through_Dark_Places)).

Later in [Divided Loyalties](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Divided_Loyalties) Lyta Alexander reveals a hidden personality in Talia that had been implanted by the Psi Corps, which later reveals to Ivanova that it had been subtly manipulating Talia's words to get to Susan.

Why was it that Jason didn't remove or permanently block this personality in Talia, considering that it couldn't have been completely undetectable if it was able to outwardly affect Talia?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Series writer J. Michael Straczynski specifically discusses these issues on the [Midwinter Lurker's Guide](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/041.html) site;

> **MW : Couldn't Ironheart have removed Control? Was Talia the original personality?**
>
> ***JMS :*** Control was the construct. The **alternate
>   personality was dormant** at the time Ironheart was there. Remember
>   that Ironheart was not seeing Talia under the best of conditions...he
>   was fighting hard NOT to use his abilities, for any reason, because it
>   created mindquakes...he was pulling everything IN. And later he was
>   shot, also not a good position.
>
> **MW: Does Psi Corps have Talia's gift now? Isn't that a problem?**
>
> ***JMS:*** Logically, yes, that would eventually pose a problem.
>
> **MW : Was the new personality formed by modifying Talia's, or was it created from scratch?**
>
> ***JMS :*** I'd rather let this aspect slide for the moment.

As you can see from the interview, he basically admits that the way in which her character was removed was clumsy and made little sense. Originally the "control" personality was going to be [Laurel Takashima](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Laurel_Takashima) but when her character was removed (after a single episode) he left in the alternate personality sub-plot as a metaphorical [trapdoor](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/misc/cc-leave.html), conveniently allowing him to remove a troublesome actor further down the road.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the originally phased-out plot twist :)